# Load picker based on firebase data

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, spinner

I am trying to load a picker with a vector based on a firebase string.

Here are my vars:

```
var modeOfLearning = [String] ()
    let modeOfLearning1 = ["Select Mode:",
                          "In Person",
                          "Web-based",
                          "Simulation"]
    let modeOfLearning2 = ["Select Mode:",
                          "In Person",
                          "Web-based"]
```

In viewDidLoad I get the value of the string from firebase and load the var modeOfLearning with either modeOfLearning1 or 2:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

let userEmail : String = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)!
        Database.database().reference().child("Student Profiles").queryOrdered(byChild: "email").queryEqual(toValue: userEmail).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String,String>

            let ustYear = snapshotValue["ustyear"]
            if ustYear == "First Year" {
                self.modeOfLearning = self.modeOfLearning1
} else if ustYear == "Second Year" {
                self.modeOfLearning = self.modeOfLearning2
}}
```

This is the pickerView function:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
return self.modeOfLearning.count}
```

The count of modeOfLearning is always zero in the pickerView func. This tells me that the pickerView func is running before the viewDidLoad is finished. How do I go about this so the pickerView func waits until the var modeOfLearning is loaded?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1- Make sure that the enclosure is been executed within the context of the main thread (or you update the values in the main thread); 2- Try calling `UIPicker#reloadAllComponents` to trigger a reloading the pickers data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this `self.modeOfLearning = self.modeOfLearning1`
try `self.modeOfLearning.append(self.modeOfLearning)`, and within the completion handler call `pickerview.reloadAllComponents()` so it triggers the picker view functions.

Comment: Thanks! just needed to reloadallcomponents